# What is the proper way to share data between a directive and a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS so i'm still struggling with my JQuery and native javascript way of thinking.

I have an app where i have 3 controllers and a custom directive and i want the directive to notify another controller than it's own parent to fetch some data.

I came up with a solution where i have following service in which have a variable containing the data, a getter and setter function and a variable which i toggle and watch in my controller for when to update.

```
myApp.service('sharedService', function () {
this.update = false;
this.data = [];

this.toggleUpdate = function(){
    if(this.update === false){
        this.update = true;
    }
    else {
        this.update = false;
    }
};

this.getData = function () {
        return this.data;
};

this.setData = function(value) {
    this.data = value;
};
});
```

In my directive i just call sharedService.toggleUpdate(); when i want the controller to fetch new data from the resource. My controller then use $scope.$watch to watch for changes on the update in my service.

```
myApp.controller('PlanController', ['$scope', 'sharedService', function($scope, sharedService){

        $scope.init = function(){
            //fetch data from API
        }

        //watch for toogling the new data
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return sharedProps.update;
        }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
            $scope.init();
        }, true);
    });
```

I hope you get the picture - is this a proper way of doing this or am i missing some easier way of doing it?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a code review which is another section in stackoverflow (correct me if I am wrong). To answer your question, yes, services are a good way to share functionality across your app. The other way is to use `$emit/$broadcast` which I use more when I want different actions in several controllers to happen in sync. `$watch` is an expensive method though so I'd try to find another way to do it (a $broadcast will do). My 2 cents..

Comment: Hey Alex C i am not exactly looking for a code review. I just wanna know how to do the notification the right way. I think your idea works for me. Can you please post an answer so i can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so here is my answer, I am not sure about the exact requirements so the answer below is just my understanding of the problem:

```
myApp.service('sharedService', [ '$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
  this.update = false;
  this.data = [];

  this.toggleUpdate = function(){

    this.update = !this.update;
    if(this.update===true){ 
      this.setData();
      $rootScope.$broadcast('onDataSet');
    }
  };

  this.getData = function () {
    return this.data;
  };

  this.setData = function(value) {
    this.data = value;
  };
}]);

myApp.controller('PlanController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'sharedService', function($rootScope, $scope, sharedService){

    $scope.init = function(){
      //fetch data from API
    }

    // Each controller would have this, rather than the $watch
    $rootScope.$on('onDataSet', function () {
      // Shared Service has been updated so let's get the data
      $scope.myObj = sharedService.getData();
    })    
});
```

Let me know if that s what you want.

Answer (score 1):

@alexc is suggesting what I would do, here is an example:

```
myApp.service('sharedService', function ($rootScope) {

    this.update = false;
    this.data = [];

    this.toggleUpdate = function() {
        this.update = !this.update;
    };

    this.getData = function () {
        return this.data;
    };

    this.setData = function(value) {
        this.data = value;
        // The data has been set so let's let everyone know
        $rootScope.$broadcast('dataSet');
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('PlanController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', 'sharedService', function($rootScope, $scope, sharedService){

    $scope.init = function(){
        //fetch data from API
    }

    // Each controller would have this, rather than the $watch
    $rootScope.$on('dataSet', function () {
        // Shared Service has been updated so let's get the data
        $scope.myObj = sharedService.getData();
    })    
});
```

If this works for you please ask @alexc to post the answer and accept his.

[Here is a good little page to visit to get more information](http://mariuszprzydatek.com/2013/12/28/sharing-data-between-controllers-in-angularjs-pubsub-event-bus-example/)

Comment: I read somewhere that it is bad practice to use the rootScope?

Comment: Not in this instance, most of what you are reading is in reference to manipulating the `$rootScope`. Meaning storing values on it, such as `$rootScope.var = 0;`, this you should not do. You can use the functions already provided on the `$rootScope`, that's what they are for.

Comment: Note: There is also `$scope.$broadcast`, but that is depending on parent/child scope relationships. There could be several `$scopes` but only (1) one `$rootScope` <- This is why manipulating `$rootScope` is bad practice